# Can I tile over existing tile (on drywall) to improve waterproofing?

Tags: plumbing

I bought a  renovated house; the shower is drop in tub, the tile wall are directly set on dry wall, no cement backer board behind the tiles. 
can I pay someone to tile over the existing tile , since the shower is not been used yet, so in this way use  the existing tile will serve as a cement backer board, for a waterproof purpose , then  attaching a 2nd layer  tile ,  if this will have a waterproofing shower wall? Or do I have to remove the new none waterproofing tile, then add the cement backer board?

Comment: I believe that cement backer board is NOT waterproof; it is not damaged by water, but lets it evaporate so you don't encapsulate the water.

Comment: Is it possible they used a paint on sealer like Red Guard, or a membrane like Kerdi, under the tile? If so, it should already be waterproof.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to the trouble and expense of re-tiling the shower, removal of the existing drywall and tile is trivial. Also, a layer of tile isn't a proper moisture barrier anyway.

I'd either seal the grout and use the shower as it is, or do it right and remove the existing.

Answer (score 1):

drywall should never, ever, ever be used for tile backer in a tub or shower, even if its water resistant.  thats a cheat that always comes back to haunt you sooner or later.  just pull it out, put up a vinyl membrane, 1/2 cement board and fiberglass lath and install your new tiles.

we just finished a job where a customer had a bathroom that had been done about 8 years ago with a drywalled and tiled tub.  the rot in the main beam below the bathtub that was caused by the drywall failure and ensuing leakage was completely invisible to them until it cost them 85 grand to fix all of the structure and completely redo the bathroom and affected areas.

do it properly and you never regret it

Answer (score 0):

There's a new shower backer board that's completely water proof and comes with the matting needed to allow your tile to adhere to it, I can't remember the name of it.
Definitely worth the money and your time. Goes in like drywall, and you seal the screws, and seams with a sealant.

Never tile over old tile or old flooring, that's just going to be an issue in the future.
I know that people cover old linoleum because of asbestos, get it removed properly and  you will have no issues also makes a good selling point on an older home.

It's always cheaper to do it right the first time than to do it right the second time.